# Using fetch with method post

Tags: ajax, react-native, fetch

I have a phonegap application that uses

```
$.ajax(
  type: 'POST,
  dataType:"json",
  url: 'test.com'
  data: { mail: 'bob@test.com' }
)
```

which i get in my glassfish server doing something like

```
HttpServletRequest request;
request.getParameter('mail');
```

I'm moving my application in react native so i'm doing

```
fetch('test.com', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ mail: 'bob@test.com' }),
})
```

but that doesn't work, my glassfish server doesn't get my parameters.
How should i do ?
It goes without saying that i don't want to make changes on the server side !

Comment: When it fails, what error messages do you see on the client side?

Comment: I don't have any error message on the client side. it's just that request.getParameter('mail'); is null on my server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example (using `$.ajax()`) you are not sending a `JSON` body.  You are actually sending a query string.  In your react example, you are sending a `JSON` body which would need to be handled differently by your server.

You will need to either change your server handler to actually accept `JSON` or you will have to send a query string with react which would look something like:

```
fetch('test.com', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
  body: $.param({ mail: 'bob@test.com' }),
})
```

If you don't have access to `jQuery` you wouldn't be able to use `$.param()`.  For this particular example, the query string you'd want to send would be

```
body: "mail=bob@test.com"
```

It is fairly straightforward to serialize data for a query string and creating a function that will do it pretty easy.

As a side note, in order to send a `JSON` body with an `$.ajax()` call, you would want to do something like this:

```
$.ajax(
  type: 'POST,
  dataType:"json",
  url: 'test.com'
  data: { mail: 'bob@test.com' }
  contentType: "application/json",
)
```

Note the `contentType` parameter which actually tells `jQuery` how to format the body of the request

Comment: unfortunaly i've tested and it doesn't work... request.getParameter('mail'); is still null

Comment: I'm still stuck, do you have any idea why this doesn't work ? what can i try ?

Comment: Do you have a way of viewing the raw value of request on the server?  That would be the next step.

Comment: Hura i got it working. I changed the value of 'Content-Type' to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' i think your answer is worth editing a bit because ajax is probably not sending plain text after all. I let you edit your answer since you are more familiar with this. Thank you for putting me in the right direction !

Comment: You're right, silly mistake on my part. Answer is edited.